# how to make jquery button controlgroup with laravel form macro?

Tags: jquery-mobile, laravel-4

I am making a jquery mobile application with laravel.

I know how to make one radiobutton with Form::macro

But what is the best way to make a button controller group just like in jqueryu mobile

For example:

```
{{
   Form::macro('jradio2', function($name,$id,$value)
   {
      return '<input type="radio" name='.$name.' id='.$id.' value='.$value.'>';

    });
 }}
 <form>
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-v-2" id="radio-choice-v-2a" value="off">
        <label for="radio-choice-v-2b">1 Gering</label>

        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-v-2" id="radio-choice-v-2b" value="other">
        <label for="radio-choice-v-2c">3 Belangrijk</label>

        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-v-2" id="radio-choice-v-2c" value="other">
        <label for="radio-choice-v-2d">7 Ernstig</label>

        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-v-2" id="radio-choice-v-2d" value="other">
        <label for="radio-choice-v-2e">15 Zeer ernstig</label>

        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-v-2" id="radio-choice-v-2e" value="other">
        <label for="radio-choice-v-2f">40 Ramp</label>

        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-v-2" id="radio-choice-v-2f" value="other">
    </fieldset>

</form>
```

If i replace the radio buttons with my selfmade macro then laravel would try and save all the radiobuttons right?
Or does the controlgroup still work?

Answer (score 0):

Foud it myself B)

```
{{Form::macro('jradio2', function($name,$id,$value,$checked)
{
    return '<input type="radio" name='.$name.' id='.$id.' value='.$value.' checked='.$checked.' >';

});
}}

{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'gotomobilepage3', 'method' => 'post')) }}

    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h3>Blootstellingsfrequentie(B)</h3>


        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">

             <label for="radio-choice-v-2a">0 Nooit</label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_blootstellingsfreq','radio-choice-v-2a' ,'0',"checked") }} 
             <label for="radio-choice-v-2b">1/2 Zeer zelden {{'(<1x/jaar)'}}</label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_blootstellingsfreq','radio-choice-v-2b' ,'0.5',"") }} 
            <label for="radio-choice-v-2c">1 Zelden{{'(jaarlijks)'}} </label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_blootstellingsfreq','radio-choice-v-2c' ,'1',"") }} 
            <label for="radio-choice-v-2d">2 Soms{{'(maandelijks)'}}</label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_blootstellingsfreq','radio-choice-v-2d' ,'2',"") }}
            <label for="radio-choice-v-2e">3 Af en toen{{'(wekelijks)'}}</label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_blootstellingsfreq','radio-choice-v-2e' ,'3',"") }}
            <label for="radio-choice-v-2f">6 Regelmatig {{'(dagelijks)'}}</label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_blootstellingsfreq','radio-choice-v-2f' ,'6',"") }}
              <label for="radio-choice-v-2g">10 Voortdurend</label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_blootstellingsfreq','radio-choice-v-2g' ,'10',"") }}

    </fieldset>


    </div>
     <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h3>Effect(E)</h3>
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
             <label for="radio-choice-v-2a">0 Geen</label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_effect','radio-choice-v-2a' ,'0',"") }} 
             <label for="radio-choice-v-2b">1 Gering</label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_effect','radio-choice-v-2b' ,'1',"") }} 
            <label for="radio-choice-v-2c">3 Belangrijk</label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_effect','radio-choice-v-2c' ,'3',"") }} 
            <label for="radio-choice-v-2d">7 Ernstig</label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_effect','radio-choice-v-2d' ,'7',"") }}
            <label for="radio-choice-v-2e">15 Zeer Ernstig</label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_effect','radio-choice-v-2e' ,'15',"") }}
            <label for="radio-choice-v-2f">40 Ramp</label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_effect','radio-choice-v-2f' ,'40',"") }}
    </fieldset>

    </div>

    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h3>Waarschijnlijkheid(W)</h3>

        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">


            <label for="radio-choice-v-2a">1/10 Bijna niet denkbaar</label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_waarschijnlijkheid','radio-choice-v-2a' ,'0.1',"") }} 
             <label for="radio-choice-v-2b">1/4 Praktisch onmogelijk</label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_waarschijnlijkheid','radio-choice-v-2b' ,'0.25',"") }} 
            <label for="radio-choice-v-2c">1/2 Denkbaar, maar onwaarschijnlijke</label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_waarschijnlijkheid','radio-choice-v-2c' ,'0.5',"") }} 
            <label for="radio-choice-v-2d">1 Onwaarschijnlijk, mogelijk in grensgeval</label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_waarschijnlijkheid','radio-choice-v-2d' ,'1',"") }}
            <label for="radio-choice-v-2e">3 Ongewoon</label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_waarschijnlijkheid','radio-choice-v-2e' ,'3',"") }}
            <label for="radio-choice-v-2f">6 Zeer wel mogelijk</label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_waarschijnlijkheid','radio-choice-v-2f' ,'6',"") }}
              <label for="radio-choice-v-2g">10 Te verwachten</label>
            {{ Form::jradio2('radio_waarschijnlijkheid','radio-choice-v-2g' ,'10',"") }}


    </fieldset>


    </div>
    {{Form:: submit("VERDER")}}
         {{ Form::close() }}

    @stop
```